# How to execute not TThread based thread in main thread?

Tags: delphi

For example from thread provided by callback from [CreateTimerQueueTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in executable or dll? It is significant to have same thread id as main thread.

```
procedure TMyMainClass.ExecuteMe(someparam: paramtype);
begin
  {something}
end;
```

and

```
procedure TimerCallback(pvContext: pointer; fTimerOrWaitFired: boolean); stdcall;
begin
  {do what ?}
end;
```

`Final update:`
All this stuff (`TThread.Synchronize`, `TThread.Queue`, `PostThreadMessage` etc) works through messages. So be sure host application of your `dll` processing messages while waiting for callback.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To execute code in the main thread, without access to a `TThread` instance, call the class methods [`TThread.Synchronize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize) or [`TThread.Queue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Queue).

If you happen to be using an old Delphi compiler that does not have those methods, then `SendMessage` or `PostMessage` with a user defined message are the simplest solution.

Comment: TThread.Synchronize requires TThread object, but callback just procedure with different thread id.

Comment: Not so. The methods I refer to are class methods and so do not need an instance.

Comment: [DCC Error] UnitMain.pas(130): E2389 Protected member 'TThread.Synchronize' is inaccessible here (Delphi XE2) on `TThread.Synchronize(qt.SendEvent)`

Comment: You need the two parameter version and pass nil as the first param.

Comment: It never able to execute function and never able to execute line 12181 `TMonitor.Exit(ThreadLock);` in System.Classes after `TMonitor.Wait(SyncProcPtr.Signal, ThreadLock, INFINITE)` when I trying to do that in dll.

Comment: In a DLL you need to call CheckSynchronize regularly to service Synchronize/Queue http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.CheckSynchronize

Comment: Thanks for suggestions but nothing works yet, I updated my post.

Comment: The question has completely morphed now. I'm confident I answered the original question. The nitty gritty of Lua I know nothing about.